# multiple canvas as buttons with onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, graphics2d

I'm having really big problems with canvas code that I'm using only 1 time in the page (in logo) working fine, and that I'm trying to use it as buttons for menu and here is the problem, I don't know really what's im doing wrong, hope some of u help me.

it's the code that I'm using for the logo and is working fine:

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>canvas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <canvas style="" width="800" id="broken-glass"></canvas>
                <h1 style="color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.95);" id="logo-title">Canvas</h1>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function() {

                    var isCanvasSupported = function () {
                        var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
                        return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
                    };

                    if( isCanvasSupported() ) {
                        var canvas = document.getElementById('broken-glass'),
                        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                        width = canvas.width = Math.min(800, window.innerWidth),
                        height = canvas.height,  
                        numTriangles = 100,
                        rand = function(min, max){
                            return Math.floor( (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min);
                        };
                        window.drawTriangles = function(){
                            context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                            var hue = rand(0,360);
                            var increment = 80 / numTriangles;
                            for(var i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) { 
                                context.beginPath();      
                                context.moveTo(rand(0,width), rand(0,height) );  
                                context.lineTo(rand(0,width), rand(0,height) );
                                context.lineTo(rand(0,width), rand(0,height) );
                                context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
                                context.fillStyle = 'hsl('+Math.round(hue)+', '+rand(15,60)+'%, '+ rand(10, 60) +'%)';      
                                context.closePath();    
                                context.fill();
                                hue+=increment;
                                if(hue > 360) hue = 0;
                            }
                            canvas.style.cssText = '-webkit-filter: contrast(115%);';
                        };
                        document.getElementById('logo-title').style.color = 'rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.95)';
                        drawTriangles();
                        var el = document.getElementById('logo');
                        el.onclick = function() {
                            drawTriangles();
                        };
                    }
                })();
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it's CSS CODE:

```
#broken-glass
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    margin-top: 27px;
    font-size: 63px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    top: 0px;

    margin-bottom: 5px;

    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;

    font-family: Calibri,"PT Sans","Trebuchet MS","Helvetica Neue",Arial;
}
```

the big problem comes when i change the id's (#*) to classes (.*) and the "id" tag to "class" tag in the html, the canvas is overlapped... the text of h1 tag is out of the canvas... and just the hell of problems, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?, how to fix it, I'm trying it during hours...

too much thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

you may try putting an !important in every code in your css.
example:

```
 text-align: center !important;
 font-weight: 700 !important;
```

this fixed my problem before, hopefully it will fix yours also.